# Move around the object using head tracking movement in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality

I am developing an app for Samsung Gear VR with unity.I have added a cube and made the cube move forward on the terrain.

Now I need to move around the cube using head tracking movement.I have referred the below link(Flyer VR movement) .But I am not able to understand the code used in it.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/movement-vr

Can anybody help me doing this in a simple way to move around the cube by head tracking